# Data binding of grouped collections with Epoxy.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

i hope you can help me, my question remains unanswered after hours of searching.

i'm using Backbone.js with Epoxy.js Views for data bindings and bound the collection to my view to show every entry:

```
var list = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model
}))();

var View = Backbone.Epoxy.View.extend({
    el: $el,
    collection: list,
    itemView: ItemView,
    bindings: { 'tbody': 'collection:$collection' }
});

new View();
```

The Model is a basic Backbone.Model, the ItemView a view representing a single entry of my collection:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar'
    }
});

var ItemView = Backbone.Epoxy.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",

    el: '<tr>'+[
        '<td class="list-foo"></td>',
        '<td class="list-bar"></td>'
    ].join('')+'</tr>',

    bindings: {
        '.list-foo': 'text:foo',
        '.list-bar': 'text:bar',
    }
});
```

Now this works like a charm, every model in my collection will be displayed in my table perfectly and any update to my list will update my views. But:

**Is there a way to group my collection, with updating my views?**

`Collection.groupBy()` returns an Array with my grouped data, but how can i handle that with `Epoxy.Views` ?

The only but ugly solution i can think of is to fill another collection with a new Model (grouped data), replace the `view.collection`, the `view.ItemView` and update the bindings, but is there no other, cleaner way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi there. any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately no - moved away from backbone a year after my post

Comment: I'm sorry, just out of curiosity, what the framework you are using now?

Comment: Currently heavily using Vue.js and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: wow! exactly my thoughts about Vue. thank you!